# Unable to upload large excel file with ajaxUpload()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, multipartform-data

When trying to import an excel file using AjaxUpload, with small file am able to perform the import. With a little larger excel file consisting of data close to 2MB, i get the below error.

Here is my ajaxUpload() inside jsp:

```
                    $.ajaxFileUpload(
                    {
                        url:'pi/importPI.do?custNamefrmList='+custNamefrmList+'&neNamefrmList='+neNamefrmList+'&bIndex='+bIndex+'+&fullPath='+fullPath+'',
                        type:"post",
                        secureuri:false,
                        fileElementId:'uploadfile',
                        method:'POST',
                        //dataType: 'json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache:false,
                        async:false,                            
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                        }
```

Apr 5, 2013 12:14:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/PMDB] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Connection reset] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    **at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)**
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:532)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:563)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:976)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:886)
    **at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:85)**
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:904)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:747)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: So is the problem that it doesn't work on any large files, or just large Excel files?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just the default Tomcat POST size limit that is preventing uploads > 2 MB.

Check here for a solution:

http://vicker313.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/increase-or-make-unlimited-maximum-post-size-in-tomcat/